# Glassfish 3.1 @Resource(..) DataSource is null at run-time

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish-3

i have set up jdbc resource in admin control panel with JNDI Name: jdbc/shop, i checked it with "Ping connection" and it succesfull

Here is bean code excerpt:

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class IndexBean {

    // from glassfish config:
    // <jdbc-connection-pool datasource-classname="org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" name="ShopPool"
    // <jdbc-resource pool-name="ShopPool" jndi-name="jdbc/shop"

    @Resource(name="jdbc/shop")
    private DataSource db;

    public IndexBean() throws SQLException {
        if(db == null) {
            System.err.println("db is null ?");
        }
    }
```

So as you guessed yet, i have constantly getting
"db is null ?" entry in log.
Any suggestions how this issue could be debugged/fixed ?
JNDI name is also 100% correct as i understand, because changing it results jndi error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your resource is not available in the bean's constructor because injection occurs *after* construction.

Use an initialization method annotated with `@PostConstruct` to get access to your resource:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
..
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
   if(db == null) {
      System.err.println("db is null ?");
   }
}
```